# Symfony add validation group to a button created in twig

Tags: symfony, validation, twig, symfony-forms

I have a form with two buttons created in twig (as suggested in best practices). one is used to submit the whole form and the other is used to upload related files. User can upload multiple files before submitting the whole form. So when the upload button is clicked, the other form fields should not be validated. I read the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/button_based_validation.html) it states that, validation can be suppressed for a specific button using:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    // ...
    ->add('previousStep', SubmitType::class, array(
        'validation_groups' => false,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

But my buttons are created in twig. How is this possible to disable validation for a button created in twig (like below)?

```
<input id="sendBtn" type="submit" value="Hinzufügen" />
```

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create you button with TWIG and not with the form builder, don't add it to your form.

If you don't want your button to validate (i.e. submit ?) your form, declare it like this :

```
<input id="sendBtn" type="button" value="Hinzufügen" />
```

(with `type="button"`, not `type="submit"`)

Comment: The code in my post is from symfony Docs. my question is how to do this in twig? my buttons are created in twig and not using ButtonType or SubmitType.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand it like that. If it is created by Twig, declare it as an `<input type="button" />` and not `<input type="submit" />`, and do not add it in your form builder

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the novalidate attribute to your createFormBuilder like so:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task, ['attr'=>['novalidate'=>'novalidate']])
```

Let us know if that works.